# How to stop a jquery function in a interval by click function?

Tags: jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I need some help finishing my little code "experience". I tried to create a browser tab notification every time there is a notice on my website. Nearly all works fine with the following code but one thing I can't get to work.

The `if (stop) return;` does not work in the middle of the code, but I would like change the tab title text back to the `current_title` when a user closes the notification.

I am not really familiar with coding and happily appreciate all help!

```
var stop = false;
var current_title = $(document).attr('title');
var titles = [
    ">>> Neue Meldung <<<",
    ">> Neue Meldung <<<<",
    "> Neue Meldung <<<<<",
    ">> Neue Meldung <<<<",
    ">>> Neue Meldung <<<",
    ">>>> Neue Meldung <<",
    ">>>>> Neue Meldung <",
    ">>>> Neue Meldung <<"];

function titleCircle(i) {
    if (stop) return;
    i = (!i) ? 0 : (i * 1 + 1) % titles.length;
    $('title').html(titles[i]);
    setTimeout(titleCircle, 1000, [i]);
};

$('div.notice-item-close').click(function () {
    stop = true;
    document.title = current_title;
});

$('.notice-item').each(function () {
    if ($(this).css("display") != "none" || $(this).css("visibility") != "hidden") {
        $(document).load(titleCircle());
    }
});

var notti_get_notice = function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            action: 'notti-inotify',
            token: notti_Notice.token
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        url: notti_Notice.ajaxurl,
        // On Successful Communication
        success: function (data) {

            if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {

                console.log(data);
                jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

                    var current_title = $(document).attr('title');
                    var stop = false;

                    $('div.notice-item-close').click(function () {
                        stop = true;
                        document.title = current_title;
                    });

                    var titles = [
                        ">>> Neue Meldung <<<",
                        ">> Neue Meldung <<<<",
                        "> Neue Meldung <<<<<",
                        ">> Neue Meldung <<<<",
                        ">>> Neue Meldung <<<",
                        ">>>> Neue Meldung <<",
                        ">>>>> Neue Meldung <",
                        ">>>> Neue Meldung <<"];

                    function titleCircle(i) {
                        if (stop) return;
                        i = (!i) ? 0 : (i * 1 + 1) % titles.length;
                        $('title').html(titles[i]);
                        var timer = setTimeout(titleCircle, 1000, [i]);
                    };
                    $(document).load(titleCircle());
                });


                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    if (value.stay === 'false') jQuery.noticeAdd({
                        text: value.text,
                        stay: false,
                        type: value.type
                    });
                    else jQuery.noticeAdd({
                        text: value.text,
                        stay: true,
                        type: value.type
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
};

window.setInterval(function () {
    console.log('Fire');
    notti_get_notice();
}, notti_Notice.frequency);
```

Comment: You just want to stop the setInterval ?

Comment: I want to stop the function titleCircle instantly by clicking on the div.notice-item-close and replace the infinite loop in browser tab with the "current_title" saved before.

Comment: Maybe, instead of `setTimeout` on the inside of `titleCircle` you can use `setInterval` on the outside, assign it to a variable then, on click, stop the `setInterval` with `clearInterval` on it. [window.clearInterval on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval)

Comment: Could you give a more spezific answer pls? Perhaps a Code example? (:

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign timeout to a variable.

```
var myTitleCircle= window.setTimeout(function());
```

Then use `clearTimeout`.

```
window.clearTimeout(myTitleCircle);
```

Comment: Where to add this exactly?

Comment: The thing is I need to use the cleartimeout outside the var notti_get_notice = function () but with having effect on exactly this function. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

setInterval may be a better solution

http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/mhof262o/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var newInterval = window.setInterval(log,1000),
        i = 0;

    function log(){
        console.log('Interval n° '+i);
        i++;
    }

    $('.clear').on('click', function(){
        clearInterval(newInterval);
    });
});
```

Comment: How Do I exactly integrate this into my existing Code? Let Me Know and i will try it out (: if it works i will accept your answer (:

Comment: It's hard to say because you have a lot of duplicates in your code (almost everything is existing 2 times) and I really don't understand the point of it. And `notti_Notice` is not defined so I can't use it.